# Why do public methods require logging calls?

Tags: java, android, logging, android-studio, public-method

I made a public class AlertDialogManager as shown below,

```
public class AlertDialogManager {

/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 * @param context - application context
 * @param title - alert dialog title
 * @param message - alert message
 * @param status - success/failure (used to set cancelable)
 * */

 public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
     Log.i("DEBUG","Alert has been called");
     new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
             .setTitle(title)
             .setMessage(message)
             .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     Log.i(CommonUtilities.TAG,"ok has been clicked");
                 }
             })
             .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     Log.i(CommonUtilities.TAG,"Cancel has been clicked");
                 }
             })
             .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
             .setCancelable(status)
             .show();
       }
}
```

So, I get this warning in android studio.

[image: Image of the warning]

As you can see the same error "'public' method 'showAlertDialog()' has no logging call
Reports any public method which does not contain a logging statement. This inspection does not report simple getters and setters"

this repeats for the class AlertDialogManager, its method showAlertDialog, and for both onClick's.

By logging I thought they meant Log.i("TAG","Message") and added them accordingly.

So, I can't seem to understand this warning. So I appreciate any help in understanding it.

Comment: that printscreen is way too small to read. afaik, logging calls are optional, not mandatory.

Comment: yeah, but I added Log and the warning did't vanish, I thought maybe I am missing something here, and try zooming on the printscreen, its high quality.

Comment: if it's just a warning, you can always ignore it. It's just the IDE being a bit overprotective, like a parent that doesn't want his kid to go outside in the summer except when wearing a thick sweater, because "it might get cold"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enabled some more lint checks - maybe all of them.
Here is a screenshot how it looks like on my side:
[image]

So here I opened the Settings, and I simply typed ***logger*** inside the search box. You can see the selected lint check: *Class without logger*
So this is inside ***Java -> Logging issues***. In my case it is not enabled, and I am using default settings for lint checks (inspections). I assume this may be more helpful for Java applications, however I have not used such logger in pure Java, so I cannot tell for sure. Anyway I would suggest that you disable this check, unless it is mandatory for your team/company...

The Log class that you use is part of Android SDK and I guess this could be a reason why it does not 'fix' the warning.